# {React Native} Firebase - updating user values before navigation only work after soft refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I have this simple code

```
 state = { email: '', password: '', userName: '', errorMessage: null }

handleSignUp = () => {     
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((userInfo) =>{ 
      userInfo.user.updateProfile({displayName: this.state.userName}).then((s) => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigator')})
  })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
}
```

Everything works as expected until the app navigates to the Navigator screen. 
Here when I log my `firebase.auth()` I get this object:

```
  Object {
        "displayName": null,
        "email": "test6@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "photoURL": null,
        "providerId": "password",
        "uid": "test6@gmail.com",
      },
```

Note how the `displayName` is null.

**Here is the issue...** Only after a soft refresh I get:

```
  Object {
    "displayName": "Bro",
    "email": "test6@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "photoURL": null,
    "providerId": "password",
    "uid": "test6@gmail.com",
  },
```

Note how the `displayName` has now a value.

What am I missing? am I using the `.then()` in the wrong order? is the promise order not correct?

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: add setTimeout to navigate to test if there is async problem
userInfo.user.updateProfile({displayName: this.state.userName}).then((s) => {setTimeout(() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigator')}, 2000)})

Comment: can you try setTimeout then we will move to the proper solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**updateCurrentUser not triggering onAuthStateChanged**

[Reference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2529)

therefore we need to reload/force update current user after update

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
```

**OR**

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```

like this

```
state = { email: '', password: '', userName: '', errorMessage: null }

  handleSignUp = () => {     
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((userInfo) =>{ 
        userInfo.user.updateProfile({displayName: this.state.userName}).then(firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()).then((s) => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigator')})
    })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
  }
```

Comment: I still get null on my next screen   useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName)})

Comment: can you reload to test before getting current user?

Comment: What do you mean by that sorry?

Comment: firebase.auth().currentUser.reload() call this function before get the current user

Comment: firebase.auth().currentUser.reload().then(()=>{
  console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName)
})

Comment: if you have any thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884123/react-native-uploading-local-image-to-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change your method like this:

```
handleSignUp = async () => {     
  const userInfo = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  await userInfo.user.updateProfile({displayName: this.state.userName})
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Navigator')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will check on this as soon as I can and I will let you know.

Comment: It still does the same effect. Only after a soft refresh I get the displayName populated