# Uploading a local stored image to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to do what should be a pretty simple operation.

I have the following image in the same directory as my app.js

```
  Project
    |______ app.js
    |
    |______ image.png
```

I would like to upload this **image.png** in my firebase storage. According to my understanding I would need to make it a **blob**.. or am I wrong? How could I tackle that?

This is my most recent attempt:

```
 var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("userImages/" + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
 ref.put('./image.png'.blob());
```

Any ideas on how I can go about doing this? Is this only possible using external libraries?

I am also looking to see if there is a proper/better way to do this over some others.

Comment: I think you need to use react-native-fs package https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs to read file. then you need to put file directly